# Identify hash function in facebook search

Tags: python, hash

I want to automatically search people in facebook by "Work" field  (see image)

It is easy to search by name only (e.g Search People by text "Peter Strang" (anywhere,  any work)

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=Piter%20Strang
```

By when I added "Work filter" = "Mail ru" the url changed

```
https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=peter%20strang&epa=FILTERS&filters=eyJlbXBsb3llciI6IntcIm5hbWVcIjpcInVzZXJzX2VtcGxveWVyXCIsXCJhcmdzXCI6XCIxMTIzMDQwMzU0NDc1NzdcIn0ifQ%3D%3D
```

How can I identify function  f, such that f("Person name", "Work name") return hash?

Example

```
f("Piter Strang", "Mail ru") = eyJlbXBsb3llciI6IntcIm5hbWVcIjpcInVzZXJzX2VtcGxveWVyXCIsXCJhcmdzXCI6XCIxMTIzMDQwMzU0NDc1NzdcIn0ifQ%3D%3D
```

[image]

Comment: That's not a hash, that's a Base64 encoded string that looks to be JSON (contents are `{"employer":"{\"name\":\"users_employer\",\"args\":\"112304035447577\"}"}`).  Note that those `%3D`s at the end of the parameter are URL-encoded equals signs; they have to be decoded before Base64 decoding will work.  I have no idea how any of this relates to your "Mail ru" filter.